# ProgressBar in TabItem Width Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar, tabcontrol

Hello dear Stack Overflow users.

I'm experiencing an issue when i place a ProgressBar within the TabControl ItemContainerStyle Template.

The issue only happens if the TabItem headers is stretched to the TabControl width. If there is only few headers, then their width is not changed and the progressbar works fine.

When the ProgressBar value changes the width of the TabItem changes with it from it's current width up to the maximum width possible for a item on that current Tab line. Other tabs on the same header line is either moved or shrinked.

So, two questions:

1. How do I avoid the headers changes their size to fit the ProgressBar?
2. Why does the ProgressBar want to be as big as possible?

**Visual Example!!**

[image: Example of issue]
**ItemContainerStyle**
(All Controls uses stretch as width)

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle"
       TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <Grid ...>
                    <ProgressBar BorderThickness="0"
                                 Background="{x:Null}"
                                 Value="{Binding Progress}">
                        <ProgressBar.Style .../>
                        <ProgressBar.Clip .../>
                    </ProgressBar>
                    <Border ...>
                        <ContentPresenter .../>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**TabControl**

```
<TabControl Name="TabController"
            TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
            Padding="0"
            helpers:TabItemGeneratorBehavior.ItemsSource="{Binding TabPageCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
            helpers:TabItemGeneratorBehavior.SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabPage, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed! Wraped ProgressBar in a Canvas and set the ProgressBar size to bind to Canvas Actual Width/Height.